# empty foreign key column in database generated by hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

hello i am using Hibernate with JPA annotation. the relation between Client and Adresse is one to many so Hibernate should create new column (id_client ) as foriegn key in the table Adresse.
My problem that i get no values in the added column how can i fix it please ?

My code XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">khaled</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate? 
useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">khaled</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
 <!--       <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">0</property> -->
 </session-factory>
 </hibernate-configuration>
```

Class Adresse :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "adresse")
public class Adresse {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id_a")
private int id;
@Column(name = "rue_a")
private String rue;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_client")
private Client c;

// getter and setters here
```

Class Client:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "client")
public class Client {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id_c")
private int id;
@Column(name = "nom_c")
private String nom;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private  List<Adresse> adr = new ArrayList<Adresse>();

// getters and setters here
```

My Main methode:

```
// get SessionFactory
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    // create session
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    System.out.println("Etat session " + session.isOpen());
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        // create client object
        Client monClient = new Client();
        monClient.setNom("rasori");

        // create adresses object
        Adresse adresseClient = new Adresse();
        adresseClient.setRue("pie IX");
        Adresse adresseClient2 = new Adresse();
        adresseClient2.setRue("sharbrook");
        monClient.getAdr().add(adresseClient);
        monClient.getAdr().add(adresseClient2);
        // start transaction
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        // save client and adresses
        session.save(adresseClient);
        session.save(adresseClient2);
        session.save(monClient);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have specified @JoinColumn in wrong entitiy. Try removing @JoinColumn from Client class and add it in Adresse class . see below

Client.java

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private  List<Adresse> adr = new ArrayList<Adresse>();
```

Adresse.java

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "adresse_id")
private Client c;
```

Comment: Yes I have tried so it works but in my data base I will get no values in id_client in adresse table

Comment: Can you please update the question accordingly

Comment: Already updated